# get the name of the class and wrap it in an if statement

Tags: python, django

I want to retrieve the name a class in a model. Can achieve that using `__class__` magic method. How can I wrap it in an `if statement` so I would make some necessary action for them.

Say, `lst = [<mammal>, <fish>, <amphibian>, <mamaal>]` then

```
if <mammal>:
  # do this
elif <fish>:
  # do fish
else:
  # do other
```

I know it's not a good way of doing things but I guess this would be by best shot. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Or `if isinstance(x, Mammal):`, which handles inheritance better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you start with something like:

```
class Mammal:
    ...

class Amphibian: 
    ...

class Fish:
    ...

animals = [Mammal(), Amphibian(), Fish()]
```

you can filter your processing of `animals` by class as follows:

```
for animal in animals:
    if isinstance(animal, Mammal):
        ...
    elif isinstance(animal, Fish):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

`isinstance` supports inheritance, so if you had a new sub-class:

```
class Bat(Mammal):
    ...
```

then

```
isinstance(Bat(), Mammal) == True
```

---

Alternatively, a more Pythonic (["EAFP"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)) approach would be to use `try` to deal with the case that some `animal`s don't support what you're trying to do with them, e.g.:

```
for animal in animals:
    try:
        animal.fly(destination)
    except AttributeError:
        animal.walk(destination)
```

This way, if you add another new class:

```
class Bird:
    ...
```

your code still works as long as the new class implements `fly` and/or `walk`, irrespective of whether it inherits from a class you're already explicitly dealing with.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but it seems like you are not doing it in the best way. Rather than check the type and do something specifically for each one, you should put the logic into the classes themselves: each class should define a `do_stuff` method and then you can simply call `animal.do_stuff()`.

Comment: Yes. I know it's not the best way. But can't think of any way there is. Thanks mate.

Comment: Well, I've suggested the better way: move the logic into the classes.